# How to merge two Firebase snapshots

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, subquery

I'm running a nested query in Firebase (using Swift).  This returns two snapshots. Normally, I store the result of query in a dictionary when there's just one snapshot

```
var query1 = [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []
query1.append(snapshot)
```

Does anyone know how to merge two snapshots to create a single dictionary entry?
The blocks look like this:

```
_refHandle = FirebaseRef.child("query1key").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
    let key2 = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("key2") as! String
    self.FirebaseRef.child("query2key").child(key2).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot2) in
        // merge the two snapshots
   })
})
```

Comment: _refHandle = FirebaseRef.child("query1key").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
    let key2 = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("key2") as!   FirebaseRef.child("query2key").child(key2).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

Comment: Not like this, edit your post with it , its really hard to read in comments, also post your JSON tree structure there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once both snapshots are available, you can take the necessary values from them and create a new object based on that information.

```
class MergedObject {
    var value1: String!
    var value2: String!

    init(value1: String!, value2: String!) {
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
    }        
}
```

Then add that object to your dictionary.

```
_refHandle = FirebaseRef.child("query1key").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
    let key2 = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("key2") as! String
    self.FirebaseRef.child("query2key").child(key2).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot2) in
        var value1 = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("value1").value as! String
        var value2 = snapshot2.childSnapshotForPath("value1").value as! String
        var mergedObject = MergedObject(value1: value1, value2: value2)
   })
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I basically came to the same conclusion too that it had to be handled outside of snapshot.